# ¿Cómo guardar cada objeto de un array como un documento independiente en mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Tengo un método como este:

```
exports.create = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { body } = req;

  let document = new Model(body);

  try {
    let doc = await document.save();
    res.status(201);
    res.json({
      success: true,
      data: doc
    });
  } catch (err) {
    next(new Error(err));
  }
};
```

Pero ahora, yo no voy a recibir un solo objeto, si no un array. Obvio sé como tomar cada objeto del array y hacer modelos con cada uno de ellos, pero ¿cómo me recomiendan subir esos varios objetos con el `let doc = await document.save();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asunto resuelto con el método `insertMany` que recibe un vector de objetos que cumplan con el modelo de Mongoose.

```
Model.insertMany(documents)
    .then(() => {
      res.status(201);
      res.json({
        success: true
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send({
        errorMessage: 'The creation of one or multiple documents failed'
      });
    });
```